# Why am I getting a Forbidden message from Keycloak after creating a new realm?

Tags: keycloak

I've setup two Keycloak docker containers behind an nginx proxy (also a docker container).  The keycloak containers are configured to join a cluster via TCPPING.  SSL is terminated at the nginx layer.  I can see both instances joining the cluster in the logs:

```
18:43:16,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
18:44:25,199 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|2] (1) [qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,205 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100001: Node qa-auth-service-172 left the cluster
18:44:25,208 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|2] (1) [qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,211 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100001: Node qa-auth-service-172 left the cluster
18:44:25,225 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|2] (1) [qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,231 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100001: Node qa-auth-service-172 left the cluster
18:44:25,232 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t4) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,232 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|2] (1) [qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,239 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100001: Node qa-auth-service-172 left the cluster
18:44:25,240 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|2] (1) [qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,241 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-15,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100001: Node qa-auth-service-172 left the cluster
18:44:25,242 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p14-t1) [Context=http-remoting-connector] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,247 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,249 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,258 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p14-t1) [Context=http-remoting-connector] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,258 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=sessions] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,260 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t4) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,260 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=sessions] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,266 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,270 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,276 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=work] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,286 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t4) [Context=clientSessions] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,288 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=work] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,291 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t4) [Context=clientSessions] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,295 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=offlineSessions] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,298 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t4) [Context=loginFailures] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,299 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=offlineSessions] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,302 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=actionTokens] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172] with topology id 6
18:44:25,303 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t4) [Context=loginFailures] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,305 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=actionTokens] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [qa-auth-service-172], topology id 7
18:44:25,700 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|3] (2) [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,705 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100000: Node qa-auth-service-172 joined the cluster
18:44:25,705 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|3] (2) [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,707 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100000: Node qa-auth-service-172 joined the cluster
18:44:25,708 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|3] (2) [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,709 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100000: Node qa-auth-service-172 joined the cluster
18:44:25,709 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|3] (2) [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,709 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100000: Node qa-auth-service-172 joined the cluster
18:44:25,709 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [qa-auth-service-172|3] (2) [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172]
18:44:25,711 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) ISPN100000: Node qa-auth-service-172 joined the cluster
18:44:26,961 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=http-remoting-connector] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:26,963 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,118 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,127 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,132 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,169 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=http-remoting-connector] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,174 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=http-remoting-connector] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,177 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=http-remoting-connector] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,236 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote] (ClusterTopologyRegistrar - 1) WFLYEJB0509: Clustered Jakarta Enterprise Beans in Node: qa-auth-service-172 are bound to INADDR_ANY(0.0.0.0). Either use a non-wildcard server bind address or add client-mapping entries to the relevant socket-binding for the Remoting connector
18:44:27,334 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=loginFailures] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,337 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=sessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,340 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,344 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,368 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=work] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,375 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-23,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=actionTokens] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,377 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,462 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=clientSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 8
18:44:27,475 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=loginFailures] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,481 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,483 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-23,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=loginFailures] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,485 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=actionTokens] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,486 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=work] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,488 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,488 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,490 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-23,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,491 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=work] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,496 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=actionTokens] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,500 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=loginFailures] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,500 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-23,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,504 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-11,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,504 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,504 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-23,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=clientSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,505 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineSessions] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,506 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=work] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,508 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,510 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=actionTokens] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,512 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=clientSessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,512 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=sessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 9
18:44:27,518 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=clientSessions] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
18:44:27,521 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=sessions] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 10
18:44:27,524 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-22,ejb,qa-auth-service-172) [Context=sessions] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [qa-auth-service-172, qa-auth-service-172], topology id 11
```

Everything appears to work fine - I can log into the Keycloak admin console with the admin user, change my profile settings, etc.

When I go to create a new Realm, I expect to be dropped into the admin console for that realm, with all the left hand nav (Realm Settings, Clients, Client Scopes, etc) available, and a summary screen for the new realm that lets me edit its basic properties (name, display name, frontend url, etc) as well as tabs for login, keys, email, themes, etc..  I.e. similar to the master Realm view:
[image]

Instead, all of the left hand nav disappears, and I get a read only overview of the general tab of the realm, and nothing else:
[image]

I can still select the master realm, and if I switch back to that everything is back to normal.

If I attempt to select the new Realm from there, I'm simply given a Forbidden screen:
[image]

From the non-deterministic nature of things, I'm guessing my login is somehow valid on one of the keycloak containers but not the other.  But I'm not seeing any errors of any kind in the output.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Your nodes have the same names,  so I guess that can be a problem for replication.

Comment: Yeah - I'm wondering about that.  I removed one of the nodes and it works fine, so it definitely is the multi-node setup that's an issue.  These are running on EC2 instances in AWS - I'm not sure how those names get generated, but each one will have a host name that starts with qa-auth-service-172 (the name of the docker container + the beginning of the private subnet I think).  How are these names generated/passed to Keycloak?  How can I change them?

Comment: Configure unique names for your keycloak containers

Comment: Yeah - I'm going to give that a try.  No env var to override that though?  It will make deployment a little more difficult because I can't simply stop/start "auth-service" - I'll have to list/grep/parse out the name if it's always unique, or somehow remember what it is.  Not the end of the world, just not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first off, the problem is because the JGROUPS clustering wasn't working as expected.  Even though the logs showed two nodes joining the cluster, they both had the same name, which apparently is enough to throw everything off.

The reason the two instances had the same name is that I was providing the hostname for the container with:

```
--hostname=(environment)-(containerName)-(privateIp)
```

This resulted in something that looked like:

```
QA-keycloak-1.2.3.4
```

Apparently either the docker startup, or the JGROUPS discovery, or something else (not exactly sure what as yet) decided it didn't like dots in the hostname, so was truncating it to simply:

```
QA-keycloak-1
```

That's a problem because with two instances in the same subnet, it obviously isn't unique.  Changing the IP address to `1-2-3-4` instead (`sed 's/\./-/g'`) gives instead:

```
QA-keycloak-1-2-3-4
```

Now both instances join the cluster with unique names, and all appears to be right with the world.